# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with Quartz in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz, component-scan

I have a Spring Boot (2.1.3) project using the Quartz scheduler. It is included via the starter:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz')
}
```

The application is (mainly) configured with component scanning. If I run the application everything is fine. If I run a test annotated with `@SprinBootTest` everything is fine, too. But if I use this custom annotation

```
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.mycompany"])
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("intTest")
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
annotation class JpaTest
```

instead of `@SpringBootTest` I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` because no Quartz `Scheduler` could be found.

I've tried to add the Quartz package to the component scan, but that doesn't help:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.mycompany", "org.quartz"])
```

How can make Spring to pick up the Scheduler with my test setup with my custom configuration annotation?

Comment: An `@ComponentScan` here is useless as it will be ignored. Also this isn't a valid annotation, as that should have something as `public @interface JpaTest`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your SpringBoot app declares `@EnableScheduling` somewhere. Try add it to your `@JpaTest`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how to fix the component scanning itself, but a workaround is to register the `Scheduler` explicitly in code:

```
@Configuration
class SchedulerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun scheduler(): Scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler()
}
```